# module.exports and scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, require

Example 1. I have a file test.js

```js
const lib = {
  foo: () => console.log(a)
};
lib.foo(); // can't access "a" before init
const a = 3;
```

Example 2. I have two files: test1.js and test2.js

```js
const lib = require('./test2');
lib.foo(); // 3
```

```js
const lib = {
  foo: () => console.log(a) 
};

const a = 3;
module.exports = lib;
```

Question: Why second example is valid?

Comment: Because you're calling `lib.foo()` after `const a`

Comment: Your second example with a module would even be valid if you did `module.exports.foo = () => console.log(a); const a = 3;` where you export the function before initialising the constant. All that matters is that it's not *called* before `a` is initialised.

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason this is valid:

```
const lib = {
  foo: () => console.log(a)
};
const a = 3;
lib.foo();
```

`a` exists before export, so it exists when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case, you are accessing the value of "a" even before you are assigning the value for "a",

in second case, it is declared then it is used, so 2nd case works good and first case gives you error